# Can't programmatically get resource from another module

Tags: android, android-resources, android-module

I have an android project with several gradle modules. Dependencies beetween modules look like this:
app  <--  coremodule <-- featuremodule

There are a resources in coremodule (strings and colors).

When I use them in layout from featuremodule everything is OK, they are avaliable and work as expected.
But when I try to get them programmaticully in Activity from featuremodule I get an exception: Unresolved reference: R

So `android:text="@string/res_from_core_module"` **works** and `myTextView.setText(R.string.res_from_core_module)` **doesn't work**.

Have anyone ideas why it happens and how to solve this?

Comment: share complete code and error details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for such behavior was adding 'coremodule'  dependency with **compileOnly**.

build.gradle for app module looked like:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compileOnly project(path: ':coremodule')
    ...
}
```

if change **compileOnly** with **implementation** (or api) everything is OK

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(path: ':coremodule')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the R points to the Resources of your app. Check the imports at the beginning of the file.

You should explicitly point the Resource folder in the method like this:

*myTextView.setText(com.coremodule.R.string.res_from_core_module)*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken R file is a common for project and modules. In any case it was the first thing which I tried - no changes. The error was the same : "Unresolved reference: R"

Answer (score 1):

Add this to all modules to share resources, classes, functions

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    ...
}
```

Comment: how does it work if I don't use dependencies from disk?

Answer (score -1):

Latest answer !!! It will make everything accessible to your app module.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    api project(': coremodule')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use like this:

```
myTextView.setText(getString(R.string.res_from_core_module));
```

Comment: setText(@StringRes) call setText(getString(@StringRes)) , so in fact there is no difference between calling this 2 methods and as a result i got the same error "Unresolved reference: R"