# How to copy resources from Project to Android Module during build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, module

My need is so simple. I have one project name as **ProjectOne** and I have a module project name as **ModuleProject** now I need to copy resources from my **ProjectOne** to **ModuleProject** during Gradle build.

Like my **ProjectOne** have an image in the drawable folder and I need to use this image in **ModuleProject** but my **ModuleProject**'s drawable folder doesn't have this image so how can I use it from the **ProjectOne**'s Drawable folder?

Comment: I think it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780412/cant-programmatically-get-resource-from-another-module

Comment: I think you can not understand my question I don't wanna use module resource in the project I want project resource to use in the module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421244/accessing-application-resources-from-the-library-project. Do you mean this one ?

Comment: Thanks brother it working thanks for your research and help.